# Is it possible to get a pet in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know that it is possible to get a horse, but I was wondering about a pet more on the lines of a dog. If it is possible, could you please provide an explanation on how to get a pet?

Comment: i had a dog following me for a while... trust me its not worth it :/

Comment: @TrewTzu It is though, if you somehow got an [immortal one](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Barbas)  Just don't try to be sneaky with any pets around.

Comment: ha i did get that one, but as a stealth archer, it didnt quite work out.

the momment i was given the choice i put him down faster then i did my companion cube

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Meeko%27s_Shack

You can get this dog just by simply going to near his house.  Make sure you follow him when you first see him.  Afterwards, unlike the dogs you buy, you can tell him to head home and later pick him back up at the shack for free again.  He does get annoying some times, since he'll run blindly into traps and bark over and over AND OVER AND OVER during important events.

Comment: XD that meeko is 1 strange dog when i got tired of his barking i send him home so that's what he did however a few meters ahead he found 5 enemies so he stopped to attack them and got killed so no more barking for me woot!! :D

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You can [summon](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Conjure_Familiar) one for a short while, or summon [four](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Flame_Thrall) ["different"](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Thrall) [permanent](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Frost_Thrall) [elementals](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_Thrall), [ask](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Meeko) one to tag along, or [buy](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vigilance_%28dog%29) one.

Comment: You can also find stray dogs in the wild, who will tag along until they're killed or you tell them to leave.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a more fixed way to get a pet, you should be able to buy a dog just outside of Markarth.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Markarth Stables. You can buy a dog there called Vigilance, I think. You can find a talking dog just outside Falkreath, but he is part of a quest. You can exploit the quest by not completing it and the dog will follow you forever until you tell him to stop. He in invincible as well. There is also a dog in Meeko's shack as said before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have researched this alot....my best outcome so far is this.  I got Meeks and brought her home to the plantation, and my adopted daughter asked if she could keep her. I asked a dawnguard husky later to follow me.  Once I arrived at home, I noticed the option to ask her to guard the farm.  So she lives outside.  Both can still follow you, only one at a time.  When you send them home they return to the plantation.  Now since I recently got the anniversary pack, my farm is packed full of pets.  Dwarf crab, rabbit, fox, goat, spider, 2 nymphs, skeever, my inside and my outside dog, a zombie dog, not sure what else is available on my vanilla game but still looking.  Maybe an armored troll can guard the farm too, who knows but along with my 2 farm hands, my Stewart, my wife, and 2 kids.....it's almost like having my own town lol oh forgot my farm has a cow, 2 goats, and a few chickens as well.

Comment: This question is about the original version of Skyrim, however.